# what is :auth in android process?

Tags: java, android

I have seen such `service` definition in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<service
    android:name="****"
    android:exported="true"
    android:process=":auth">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="****"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

I am wondering what is

```
 android:process=":auth">
```

I think it is regarding authentication protocol or so, but I am not sure what it does and what ":auth" stands for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
android:process="string"
```

If the name assigned to this attribute begins with a colon ('`:`'), a new process, private to the application, is created when it's needed and the service runs in that process. If the process name begins with a lowercase character, the service will run in a global process of that name, provided that it has permission to do so. This allows components in different applications to share a process, reducing resource usage.

Source: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element.html#proc